# Tabview to follow all activities

Tags: android, tabview

Im new to android and i am trying to develop a simple application with tabhost. And i want the tabhost to be in all of my activites. I have 5 tabs and 6-7 activites, and i want them all to be shown in those five tabs.

Here i create my tabactivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs" />

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

         />
</RelativeLayout>

</TabHost>
```

And here i add tabs:

```
    TabSpec tabSpec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1");
    tabSpec.setIndicator("Map",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.world));
    Context ctx = this.getApplicationContext();
    Intent i = new Intent(ctx, DealFinderActivity.class);
    tabSpec.setContent(i); 
    mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec); 

    mTabHost.getTabWidget().setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2").setIndicator
            ("List Deals",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.database))
            .setContent(new Intent(this,ListDeals.class)));

    //      TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview3);
    //      textView.setText("hello");
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test3").setIndicator("Favorites",
            res.getDrawable(R.drawable.heart)).setContent(
                    new Intent(this, ListDeals.class)));

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test4").setIndicator("Settings",
            res.getDrawable(R.drawable.preferences)).setContent(
                    new Intent(this, DealDescription.class)));

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test5").setIndicator("About",
            res.getDrawable(R.drawable.newspaper)).setContent(
                    new Intent(this, DealDescription.class)));
```

And in the ListDeals.class i use this to change to a new activity:

```
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
                DealMyAss.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        getApplication().startActivity(myIntent);
```

But here the tabview disappears??

Any ideas how i can keep the tabview??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[ActivityGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html) is what you are looking for .

as name suggest it ambeds multiple activities within a tab .
go through examples . one is [here](http://united-coders.com/nico-heid/use-android-activitygroup-within-tabhost-to-show-different-activity) .

Create one ActivityGroup for every tab .

Comment: Just want to add that ActivityGroups are deprecated in ICS. Better to use Fragments.

Comment: Yes i followed the example and it works just fine, but i have an Map class where i have clickable overlays, and those overlays are in MyItemizedOverlay and in that class there is a onTap method to change the class, in that class i cant make it change??

Comment: I get this error when trying to change from another class, java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.application

Comment: The code for it:

 protected boolean onBalloonTap(int index, OverlayItem item) {

        Intent previewMessage = new Intent(c, DealDescription.class);
        TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)c;
        parentActivity.startChildActivity("ArrowsActivity", previewMessage);
  return true;